# variables with requieJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My call to requireJS in on my index page, what I want to know is it possible for me to get a variable out of a function that is on my index page and use it as a condition in my main.js file? I am trying to have a script be used based on a variable on my index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your wariable to be accesible on both index and main pages, then create separate requireJS module, put yuor variable in there and reference this module wherever you need it.

So, assuming that you already have two modules: index.js and main.js, you can create third module, let's call it "myVariables.js". Create that file and inside put something like this:

```
define(function() {

    var vm = {
        myGlobalVariable = "Hello"
    };

    return vm;
});
```

Then in your other modules you can reference to this module, for example like this:

```
var myVariabledModule = require('myVariables');
alert(myVariablesModule.myGlobalVariable);
```

This should give you and allert with the "Hello" string and this code should work in any module of your application.

Comment: im an very new to this and im not sure i understand what you mean? is there an example of this somewhere?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this. Will this work if I use it on my index.html page? The variable that i am trying to capture is in a function on that page.